# How does one climb up/down ladders the quickest?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-source

I play a lot of Zombie Escape, and there is always a lot of ladder climbing.

What I have noticed however, is that some players climb the ladders faster than others, while others climb it slower.

Is there a trick to this?  Is there a certain way to approach the ladder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way to climb up/down a ladder is to face the ladder on an angle (so you are perpendicular to the ladder) and look straight up to the sky then use a combination of the up key with a left/right key to move diagonally on the ladder.

**To climb up**

Left arm closest to ladder - Strafe left and go forward (default keys: A+W)

Right arm closest to ladder - Strafe right and go forward (default keys: D+W)

**To climb down**

Left arm closest to ladder - Strafe left and go backward (default keys: D+S)

Right arm closest to ladder - Strafe right and go backward (default keys: A+S)

Comment: +1. It certainly worked in 1.6 and earlier versions. However I'd write `Strafe left and go forward` instead of `HOLD A + W` because some players re-assign the controls ;)

Comment: So does this apply to CSGO and CSS?

Comment: Works in CS + CSS, but since climbing up ladders in CSGO has been made quicker than it's predecessors, it is difficult to speculate whether or not this method works.

Comment: I've found that not looking straight up, but actually looking at at the ladder in a 45 degree (from straight up) angle makes you quite a bit faster (from a surf map that had a speedometer, might be airaccelerate related though)